# Cocoa NsView doesn't show the image

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsimage

I am stuck with a problem I can not solve. I'm trying to show a small avatar in my app. 
I created an NSView class, then add in interface builder a Custom View, and link it to the class.

It gives me no errors, but it doesn't diplay the image!

This is my .m NSView class file:

```
    #import "Avatar.h"

@implementation Avatar

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(10, 10, 400, 300);
        imageView = [[NSImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        [imageView setImageScaling:NSScaleToFit];
        NSImage *theImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"/Users/blabla/nonloso/prova.jpg"];
        [imageView setImage:theImage];
        [self addSubview:imageView];
    } 
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    // Drawing code here.
}

@end
```

This is my .h NSView class file:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Avatar : NSView {
@private 
    NSImageView *imageView;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

`[-NSImage imageNamed]` doesn't work that way – see [its documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSImage/imageNamed%3a).

You probably need `-initWithContentsOfFile:` instead.

Comment: Is `theImage` non-nil after the call to `-initWithContentsOfFile:`?